Creating a generalised correction factor using the results of a polynomial regression?
I have taken measurements of CO2 using two different gas analysers one of these is more commonly used within my field so I would like to treat these measurements as my "reference" and the other is a newer piece of equipment. The relationship between the measurements from these two analysers is non-linear so I have used a second order polynomial regression.
NA=1079.64+9117.71⋅(Ref−μ)+2896.35⋅(Ref−μ)2
Here μ is the mean of LGR.
I am hoping to use this equation to create a correction factor so that I can bring the NA measurements in line with the Reference analyser measurements. Is this possible?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
